Azure table input function returns 500 if no matching record found
I have written azure isolated table input function(.net 8) which return 500 if no matching record found. Previously in .net 6, it used to return null object. Can someone please guide to handle it in function signature ?
 public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "partition/{partitionkey}/row/{rowkey}")] HttpRequest req,
                                              [TableInput("LogTable", "{partitionkey}", "{rowkey}", Connection = "ConnectionString")] TableEntity tableEntity,
                                              string partitionkey,
                                              string rowkey)
 {
// proceed with tableEntity record.
{

This code works fine if matching record (partition key + row key) found and return exact one row. But throws 500 error if no record exsists in table for the given key as "Cannot convert input parameter 'tableEntity' to type 'Azure.Data.Tables.TableEntity' from type 'Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Grpc.Messages.GrpcModelBindingData'. Error:Azure.RequestFailedException: The specified resource does not exist."

Check if below solution helps to resolve the issue

As mentioned in article, use below code to handle the "No Matching Record Found error" in .NET 8 Isolated Azure Function.
Code Snippet:
[Function("MyFunction")]
public string Run([IsolatedTableInput] MyTable myTableInput)
{
    if (myTableInput == null || myTableInput.Rows == null || !myTableInput.Rows.Any())
    {
        return "No matching records found";
    }
    // Process the data
    var result = myTableInput.Rows.Select(row => row.Value);
    return string.Join(", ", result);
}

I have created an Azure isolated table input function.
Code:
        [Function("Function1")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "partition/{partitionkey}/row/{rowkey}")] HttpRequest req,
            [TableInput("Table1", "{partitionkey}", "{rowkey}", Connection = "demo")] TableEntity tableEntity)
        {

            if (tableEntity == null || tableEntity.RowKey == null || !tableEntity.RowKey.Any() || !tableEntity.PartitionKey.Any())
            {
                return new OkObjectResult("No matching records found");
            }
            else
            {
                return new OkObjectResult($"Found record with partition key '{tableEntity.PartitionKey}' and row key '{tableEntity.RowKey}'");

            }
        }

Response:

